# How to handle consumer offset when kafka switches from production cluster to DR setup?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

Trying to setup kafka DR cluster using mirror maker. How I can ensure that kafka consumers will not process duplicate messages when kafka switches to DR setup ?

Is there a way to replicate the consumer offset from production kafka cluster to DR cluster ?